# Ajax not working with .htaccess`rewrite url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I create the basic project and use htaccess rewrite url and jquery ajax
.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
    RewriteEngine On  
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f      
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1
```

gallery.php :

```
<script type="text/javascript">                
    window.onload = function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/test1/controller.php",
            data: {brand:"<?php echo $id;?>"},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.response)
            }
        });
    }
```

controller.php :

```
$brand=$_REQUEST['brand'];
        $arr = array ('response'=>$brand.'___jason','comment'=>'test comment here');
        echo json_encode($arr);
```

but when write url in  address bar of browser like:

```
http://localhost/test1/gallery/gucci
```

jquery ajax not working but when write :

```
http://localhost/test1/gallery
```

jquery ajax is working well.

I must use end of url (gucci) for id , but when I write it, jquery isn't working

Answer (score 0):

First of all... You are not telling us what framework or what software you're running there.

Use firebug or other console addons depending on your browser, open it up, go to the console tab, refresh the page... you should see an ajax call over there and then you can click it, and view exactly what's wrong, or what errors you get, even what you send.

See this: http://screencast.com/t/5TQhLOzKq5

Example in case your jQuery isn't loaded properly you will be getting a $ is undefined, in the console or js error console

Answer (score 0):

When using relative paths for your ajax calls with url rewriting keep in mind that the **directory is changing relatively to your url**.

To avoid this behavior use absolute paths or set in your html the base tag like this:

```
<base href='http://your-server-address.com'/>
```